# Pagination With Aerospike Nodejs client

Tags: node.js, lua, pagination, aerospike

I have server setup with nodejs and Aerospike. I want to implement pagination for listing all the data in on of the sets on aerospike database. Aerospike does not seem to support sql query params like `limit`, `orderBy` or `skip`. Using LList partially solves the issue as the data is by default ordered by key. Also maybe using Aerospike Lua List we can partially implement a UDF to use `list.take(number of elements from start)`.
However as the set is suppose to grow very large over time, OrderBy and Skip become very important and cannot be implemented efficiently by UDF filtering.
Can any suggest on how to handle this ?

Comment: Take will alter the list. I guess what you want is a find? The NodeJS-Client seems to be behind what the server and other clients support. You could take a look at how findFrom(startValue, COUNT ) is implemented: http://bit.ly/1N3ynLg (check out implementation on github java client repo)

It all boils down to calling the right UDFs on server side so if you find out how to call the udf for findFrom, you can use that for your pagination. However, you'll need to call size() separately if you don't want to write an UDF that gives you both count and data within the same call.

Comment: Order-by is not supported, you only have 1 key to sort by. Modelling with multiple lists might come to the rescue.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, Aerospike does not support limit & orderby kind of queries. A way to work around the limitation is to create a secondary index on a column and do secondary index range query. Say you create a column with monotonically increasing values. You can do a range query from 1-50 and then 51-100 and so on.

You can use UDF with aggregation where you filter the records. But it will not be very efficient as the set scan will process all the records of the set and the UDF filter will only give 50 (some n) results back. As the set size grows, you will end up wasting lot of processing.